# Parabolic antenna - prove all incoming rays are reflected into a common point

Tags: conic-sections, curves

I have this question;
Consider the parabolic antenna below. Suppose, the dish is a surface patch parametrised by

$$r:\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 :x^2 +y^2 =1\}\to \mathbb{R}^3;\\ (x,y)\mapsto(x,y,1-(x^2 +y^2))\in\mathbb{R}^3.$$

Prove that all incoming rays parallel to the $z$ axis are reflected into a common point.

Find the coordinates of this point (the point at which to mount the actual antenna).

[Hint: use and prove the fact that an incoming ray with direction $v$ is reflected in $r(x, y)$ into an outgoing ray of direction $v′ = v − 2(N(x, y)\cdot v)N(x, y)$.]

I'm really stuck and don't know what to do. I've found the normal vector but that's as far as I've got. Any help would be much appreciated! This is for a Maths course, not a Physics course so I don't have any knowledge of general physics properties.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Finding the normal is a good start. (You should include what you got as part of your question.) Now, think about how mirrors work: *"angle of incidence = angle of reflection"*. A normal is perpendicular to the mirror, so it bisects the angle between an incoming and reflected ray. See what you can do with that and [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3519629/edit) with your attempts (comments are easily overlooked). This will help answerers tailor responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know.

Answer (score 0):

$z = 1 - (x^2+y^2)$
This is a parabola that points down?

Our normal:

$N(x,y,z) = (\frac {dz}{dx}, \frac{dz}{dy}, -1) = (-2x, -2y, -1)$ points the right way.

The unit normal $n =  \frac {N}{\|N\|} = (\frac {-2x}{\sqrt{ 1+4x^2 + 4y^2}}, \frac {-2y}{\sqrt{ 1+4x^2 + 4y^2}}, \frac {-1}{\sqrt{ 1+4x^2 + 4y^2}})$

Angle of incidence:

$\cos \theta = (0,0,-1) \cdot n = \frac {1}{\sqrt{ 1+4x^2 + 4y^2}}$

Equals the angle of reflection.

$\cos 2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta - 1 = \frac {1-4x^2 - 4y^2}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}$

The direction of our reflected beam.

$(\frac {-4x}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}, \frac {-4y}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}, \frac {1-4x^2-4y^2}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2})$

If take the point of incidence and add this vector, scaled such that we get back to the axis of symmetry.

$(x,y,1-x^2 - y^2) + \frac {1+4x^2 + 4y^2}{4}(\frac {-4x}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}, \frac {-4y}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}, \frac {1-4x^2-4y^2}{1+4x^2 + 4y^2}) = (0,0,\frac 14)$

Comment: How did you get cos(theta) to equal (0,0,-1)•n?

Comment: $(u-v)\cdot (u-v) = \|u-v\|^2 = \|u\|^2 + \|v\|^2 -2u\cdot v.$  Compare that to the law of cosines.  $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 -2ab\cos C$ and you arrive at the conclusion that $u\cdot v = \|u\|\|v\|\cos\theta$